# Retrieve and Instantly Update High Score From Two Separate SKScene's

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, userdefaults

In my GameScene I have a score that is being saved at the end of the game via UserDefaults. Below is my GameScene code for saving the score.

```
var totalPoints = 0 {
        didSet {
            score.text = " \(totalPoints)"
            UserDefaults.standard.set(totalPoints, forKey: "scoreDefaults")
        }
    }
```

Once the player loses all their lives, the game then returns you back to the Main Menu scene. In this scene I would like to instantly retrieve and update the high score number on the Main Menu scene if the players last score was higher than the higher score they had before. But for some reason it just constantly updates every score the user gets at the end of the game regardless if it's higher or lower than the last high score. What am I doing wrong? Below is my Main Menu scene. When I print "newScore" and "getScore" I do see the right values but my code must be wrong when it involves updating the high score when needed.

```
let getScore:Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "scoreDefaults")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        


    if ((UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")) >= 0) {
                highScore.text = " \(newScore)"
            } else {
                print("I don't know")
            }

            if (getScore > newScore) {
                print("New High Score!")
                newScore = getScore
                //print(newScore)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")
                highScore.text = " \(newScore)"
            } else {
                print("Not a high score")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")
                highScore.text = " \(newScore)"
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are wrong `scoreDefaults` vs  `updateHighScoreDefaults`  Pick 1

Also, `getScore` is only called once,  make it a computed property instead

`var getScore:Int  {return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")}`

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        

        if (getScore > newScore) {
            print("New High Score!")
            newScore = getScore
            //print(newScore)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")

            highScore.text = " \(newScore)"
        } else {
            print("Not a high score")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults")
            highScore.text = " \(newScore)"
        } 
        UserDefaults.syncronize()
}
```

Comment: Should I move my code to the update function so it updates the high score right away or didMove is fine?

Comment: neither,  do it on `didSet` of `newScore` if you want to to update constantly. I do not know what you are doing,  i just assumed this was like a high score scene or something.

Comment: Please take a look at my code again. As you can see I have two different keys because I would like to get the originaql score from GameScene which is through "scoreDefaults" and would like to save it (newScore, forKey: "updateHighScoreDefaults") so I can constantly update the high score on the main menu through updateHighScoreDefaults everytime the players opens the app. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: but you never read from `updateHighScoreDefaults`  I do not recommend using `UserDefaults` as a mean of sharing data,  I know you CAN do it, doesnt mean it is a good way to do it.  `UserDefaults`  Should be used as a way to keep settings of your app in a certain state.  I would recommend using the `userData` that is on every scene to get your score from GameScene to MenuScene, then use `UserDefaults` to save to device

Comment: You do not need an example, just look it up in apple documents.  userData is a dictionary reference attached to a node,  everything else should be basic understanding of how a dictionary works